# Communicating with an Android service Via. two different callers

Tags: android, service

I have a long running service which is started and stopped by the applications main activity however I also what this service to be updated by an alarm.

I believe I've read somewhere that you can only have one instance of a service running at anyone time, so can I just *start* the service from both the activity and the Alarm's Reviver?   if so does the GC take care of the old instance of the service, or is their no *old* instance as the second call *starts* the same instance?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using a started service as opposed to a bound service. When you call `startService()` the first time, the service is "created" (i.e., `onCreate()`) is called. After that, any time you call `startService()`, the `onStartCommand()` is called.

So yes - a single instance of the service is running at any time. You can just call `startService()` from both the `Activity` and the `AlarmReceiver` and the Intent will be delivered to the `Service` if it has already been created; else the `Service` is created and then the `Intent` is delivered to it.

Comment: Thanks - yes I'm not using a bounded service, just a straight called one.